# sentence construction where non-restrictive clause uses a conjunction

Tags: expression-choice

> It gave John, a new hire to the company and now a director, a good start.
>
> It gave John, a new hire to the company who is now a director, a good start.

The non-restrictive clause uses "and" to connect two phrases. Somehow MS word does not like the first construction. And the second construction is not elegant to read.

I could try this but too many commas and two non-restrictive clauses are also not easy read.

> It gave John, a new hire to the company, now a director, a good start.

What could be good substitutes while still using the non-restrictive clause?

Comment: Your first version is fine. Ignore Word's grammar check - it doesn't understand what you're doing. Ignore Word's grammar check even when it does understand what you're doing.

Comment: I expect Word (which is only dumb software, after all) is bothered by your jargonny non-standard use of ***hire*** as a noun in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - *(A) new hire* meaning 'person newly hired' is everyday usage in the US.

Comment: It's used in the UK and Australia as well. It's common in the HR world; if that makes it "jargonny," then so be it. But it's common enough I wouldn't call it "non-standard."

Comment: It's not an issue with the hire (standard usage), it's a construction issue. Besides ignoring ms word warnings, which can be useful to double check potential issues, what could be the good substitutes. I see the third version a good alternate except for its readability with the extra comma. If there is a way i can justify dropping the second comma in the third version, then that could be a good solution.

Comment: @Erik If FF had his way, there'd be plenty of new fires at a certain software company.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - How un-British of him! Most Englishmen would only have micro-scoffed.

Comment: I don't like the sequencing in the original, irrespective of worries about acceptable forms of construction. I'd use a variant of 'It gave John, a new hire to the company, a good start. _He is now a director_.'

Comment: @Erik Yes, we often have to eat our words. But find some pseudowords (or worse) hard to swallow.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I agree with your approach of rewording. Another possible variant: "It gave John, newly hired as a director, a good start in the company".

Comment: @Erik Kowal Oh, you use 'hire' as a verb over there?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - It's considered politer than calling it 'renting'.

Comment: Haven't you changed the meaning with your variant, Erik?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Maybe so: it's quite possible that it might not fit with the OP's context. But I think we have at least demonstrated to him that there are other workable ways of solving his conundrum.

Comment: Why try to put everything into one sentence? This is what paragraphs are for. Seriously, since parenthetic material is spoken with a lower intonation, putting it in the middle of a sentence makes it sound very strange.

Comment: Just so we're clear. I've no objection to ***hire** = a person hired* as such. But it's a terrible fit with such a structurally complex sentence. I also wouldn't expect that level of complexity in text that's presumably just intended to *convey information succinctly*. Which is to say it's not finely-honed prose to be savoured slowly, taking the "scenic route" with creative and teasing variations on the straightforward route.

Comment: It looks like Erik phrasing changes the meaning. It has to be very length conscious so can't use the two sentence form either.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, I would say that the grammar checker in your copy of Word is under the impression that you are talking about either three people—(1) John, (2) a new hire to the company, and (3) a director— or two people—(1) John, a new hire to the company, and (2) a director—that have gotten off to a good start thanks to the "it" at the beginning of the sentence. Having utterly misinterpreted the sentence on that first point, Word doesn't know what to make of the word *now*, and it is baffled by the punctuation currently in place; hence the daunting stretch of green squiggly underlining.

I strongly support StoneyB's recommendation that you ignore Word's grammar checker. Someday, when computers are far more sophisticated about natural languages than they are today, they will laugh about how humans once sought to placate them with rewrites whenever the computers' word-processing programs greenlined perfectly acceptable wording that the programs' clunky software rules couldn't parse correctly.

Having said all that, I just pasted the sentence "It gave John, a new hire to the company and now a director, a good start." into my copy of Word for Mac 2011, and the program didn't raise any grammatical flags about the sentence. So maybe Word is already smarter than it was in the heyday of the version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If some time has passed since John was hired (and apparently it has, although conceivably he might have been hired on AS a director—we don't know whether "it" happened at this job or some previous one) then he is NOT a new hire, any more than anyone else who works at the company.  Perhaps it meant "John, hired fairly recently and already a Director,"    This indicates an unusually quick promotion, whereas both original constructions leave that in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

MS Word is not a good teacher of style, so start by taking its complaints with a decent measure of salt.  The phrase following "John" in the original sentence is called an appositive, something that is in effect a grammatical duplication of what it follows, and is used to further identify it.  So, grammatically, you're good.  There is a bit of a semantic issue, though.  The verb "gave" is past tense; the word "now" implies present tense.  One might gather that John's good start was given some time in the past, but that his ascension to director occurred relatively recently.